# Intermittent "Context Canceled" error on Terraform Plan

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, aws-codebuild, python-3.9, terraform-aws-modules

I'm running a terraform plan through AWS Codebuild. terraform init works consistently but terraform plan intermittently throws this error:

> Error: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

- terraform version: 0.12.31
- aws provider version: ~> 3.55.0

The intention here was to change Python lambda runtimes from 3.6 to 3.9. In this regard, I upgraded terraform from 0.12.21 to 0.12.31 and aws provider version from ~>2 to ~> 3.55.0 (aws provider version 3.55.0 is the first version that supports python 3.9 runtime)

I've seen that others have had similar issues and what seemed to have worked for them is trying a different version of the provider. I wanted to keep these versions of terraform and aws provider because if I upgrade it further here, it would have consequences elsewhere in our pipeline. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can move forward?

Comment: "context cancelled" is the default error message for the mechanism in the Go programming language to implement cancellation of a running request, so I'm not entirely sure what's going on here but it seems like something in your environment is sending an interrupt signal to either Terraform or the provider, which therefore causes the AWS provider to exit with this error.

Comment: I'm running this on AWS Codebuild. My best guess is that Codebuild is somehow running out of memory and that's causing the interrupt. Thanks for confirming some of my suspicions though

Comment: I think I've finally solved it. I increased the Compute resources allocated to Codebuild by following this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/change-project-cli.html
All my builds are running through successfully now. So it looks like it was just the resource constraint all along. Thanks @MartinAtkins!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved it. I increased the Compute resources allocated to Codebuild by following this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/change-project-cli.html

All my builds are running through successfully now. So it looks like it was just the resource constraint all along.